# Include all folder files in a shared project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, shared-project

One of the advantages of .NET Core project format is that the *.csproj file doesn't contain the list of files to be included in the project anymore, it just includes everything in that folder.

But [Shared Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows) still have the old .NET Framework project format in the sense that there is a *.projitems file that lists files to be included in the project

```xml
<Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\MyFile.cs" />
```

Every time you add a new file to the project, it is added to the *.projitems file which often results in source control conflicts.

Is there some way to ignore this *.projitems file and include all files in the project folder, like .NET Core projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to include all *.cs files by default with a wildcard like this:

```xml
<Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\**\*.cs" />
```

When copying a file into the project folder using Windows Explorer, it should pick it up automatically. But if you add a new file from Visual Studio, it will still add a new `<Compile>` entry, but that can be reverted using source control. Not a perfect solution, but it mostly works.